# XCode 6 Beta 6 Error in Beta 7 - Value of optional type not unwrapped

Tags: core-data, swift, xcode6, xcode6-beta7

I've been trying to do a simple CoreData task, saving data. I'm sure it works in Beta 6, but errors starting appearing after updating to Beta 7.

I think I have to add '?' or '!' based on the error hint, but just not smart enough to figure out where!

```
    @IBAction func saveItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Reference to App Delegate

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    // Reference our moc (managed object content)

    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Create instance of our data model and initialize

    var newItem = Model(entity: ent, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Map our attributes

    newItem.item = textFieldItem.text
    newItem.quanitity = textFieldQuantity.text
    newItem.info = textFieldInfo.text

    // Save context

    contxt.save(nil) 
}
```

The error says

```
Value of optional type 'NSEntityDescription?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

At the line

```
var newItem = Model(entity: ent, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
```

Everytime I seem to have clear the error and compiles ok, clicking the 'Save' shows in the debug area

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly trivial, there's not much to analyze here. Try changing this:

```
let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context)
```

to this

```
let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
```

As always, novices tend to overlook tell-tale signs. The error clearly states that the optional is of type `NSEntityDescription`. And given that there is only object of this type being instantiated in the given code, it doesn't take a genius to guess where the error lies.

```
Value of optional type 'NSEntityDescription?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

Also, method used here to instantiate the NSEntityDescription object is declared as follows:

```
class func entityForName(entityName: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSEntityDescription?
```

... the `?` character clearly telling us that this method returns an optional.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the `Model` initializer signature is:

```
init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext)
```

the compilation error happens because `NSEntityDescription.entityForName` returns an optional, so you have to unwrap it.

As for the runtime error, my guess is that `contxt` is nil, and you are passing a forced unwrapped here:

```
let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)
```

To made code safer and more clear, I'd explicitly use optionals:

```
let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext? = appDel.managedObjectContext
if let contxt = contxt {
    let ent: NSEntityDescription? = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Create instance of our data model and initialize

    if let ent = ent {
        var newItem = Model(entity: ent, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
    }
}
```

and use debugger & breakpoints to check if any of the mentioned variable is nil.